# Search page is not shown properly with D7 custom theme

Tags: theming, search

I am currently building a D7 theme for a website. I experiment some problems with the search page. After entering a search term the page "domain.com/search/node/[searched term]" is opened. But it just show the base page with nothing in the main-content block.

With another theme it works : results are shown properly on the search page and I can see both node tab and user tab. I assume something is wrong in my theme. I try to override 
"search-results.tpl.php" because I read that this template is used to build the search page, but in my case it seems that the template is not used because if I put this code on it :

```
<?php print "foo"; ?>
```

there is no changes on the search page.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Obvious first questions: Did you place the tpl file in the correct folder? Did you clear the theme cache?

Comment: Yes I already check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solve the problem. The problem was my implementation of the template page "page.tpl.php" because inside this I never call :

```
<?php print render($page['content']); ?>
```

As a consequence the results of the search were never shown, so I can't saw changes made in "search-results.tpl.php" ...